# Не понимаю что происходит в коде

Tags: c#

я владею базовым си шарпом и не понимаю что происходит в этом коде с Leetcode. Я решил задачу при помощи List в VS верно, но решение считается не верным, т,к я не понимаю что происходит в этом коде. Я понимаю что это реализация связного списка в си шарп, но я так и не понял что происходит в этих строчках. B что значит next в данном коде.
Буду благодарен если поможете разобраться. Спасибо.

> public ListNode next;

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     public int val;
 *     public ListNode next;
 *     public ListNode(int val=0, ListNode next=null) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.next = next;
 *     }
 * }
 */
```

Comment: Вам знакомо понятие связного списка, но непонятно, что такое next у узла ??

Comment: @MBo ну я пишу на ООП шном языке всего месяц, и не всю документацию Learn читал, или может что то забыл. Очень тяжело учить что то сложнее базы не зная не единого языка, так я не понимаю многих вещей которые используются в документации для описания чего либо. Если это возможно не могли бы вы дать ссылку на статью об этом.

Comment: ООП здесь ни при чём, это структура данных такая - называется "связный список", погуглите. И это разновидность "связного списка" - односвязный список. Собственно там в комментарии так и написано - "singly-linked list".

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Связный_список ; https://metanit.com/sharp/algoritm/2.1.php ; https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1?view=net-8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простейший односвязный список.

Например можно создать ноду

```
var node1 = new ListNode(42);
```

Теперь можно создать ещё парочку, но указывая ссылку на ранее созданную ноду

```
var node2 = new ListNode(123, node1);
var node3 = new ListNode(6543, node2);
```

Вот и создался односвязный список из 3 нод. Теперь можно по нему прогуляться циклом

```
var node = node3;
while (node != null);
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.val);
    node = node.next;
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
6543
123
42
```

---

Можно даже так, с циклом `for`

```
for (var node = node3; node != null; node = node.next)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.val);
}
```

Comment: Ок, я уже разобрался спасибо, знал много теории, но не понимал как работает на практике, я пользовался уже реализованным стандартным классом List<t> и его методами. У меня вопрос, я правильно понимаю что то что выше это структура данных - односвязный список а List это динамический массив?

Comment: @Tarun верно, `List<T>` работает на основе массивов.